# how to define two tokens as one token?

Tags: python, lexical-analysis, ply

I am trying to define two words separated by space as one token in my lexical analyzer
but when I pass an input like `in out` it says `LexToken(KEYIN,'in',1,0)`
and `LexToken(KEYOUT,'out',1,3)`
I need it to be like this `LexToken(KEYINOUT,'in out',1,0)`

PS: `KEYIN` and `KEYOUT` are two different tokens as the grammar's definition

Following is the test which causes the problem:

```
import lex
reserved = {'in': 'KEYIN', 'out': 'KEYOUT', 'in\sout': 'KEYINOUT'} # the problem is in here

tokens = ['PLUS', 'MINUS', 'IDENTIFIER'] + list(reserved.values())

t_MINUS = r'-'
t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_ignore = ' \t'

def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z]+([(a-zA-Z)*|(\d+)*|(_*)])*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'IDENTIFIER')  # Check for reserved words
    return t


def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0], "at line", t.lexer.lineno, "at position", t.lexer.lexpos)
    t.lexer.skip(1)


lex.lex()
lex.input("in out inout + - ")
while True:
    tok = lex.token()
    print(tok)
    if not tok:
        break
```

Output:

```
LexToken(KEYIN,'in',1,0)
LexToken(KEYOUT,'out',1,3)
LexToken(IDENTIFIER,'inout',1,7)
LexToken(PLUS,'+',1,13)
LexToken(MINUS,'-',1,15)
None
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I placed the sample in a small program, it worked fine for me. Please provide an [mcve] illustrating the failure.

Comment: That is quite different and the problem should be obvious: `reserved.get` doesn't do a regex match, and in any case `in out` isn"t a match for the `IDENTIFIER` regex.

Comment: Why it shouldn't match with `KEYINOUT`? I need it to match with `KEYINOUT`. And when I do it without `\s` and I put a space, it causes the same problem again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your function which recognizes `IDENTIFIER`s and keywords:

```
def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z]+([(a-zA-Z)*|(\d+)*|(_*)])*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'IDENTIFIER')  # Check for reserved words
    return t
```

First, it is clear that the keywords it can recognize are precisely the keys of the dictionary `reserved`, which are:

```
in
out
in\sout
```

Since `in out` is not a key in that dictionary (`in\sout` is *not* the same string), it cannot be recognised as a keyword no matter what `t.value` happens to be.

But `t.value` cannot be `in out` either, because `t.value` will always match the regular expression which controls `t_IDENTIFIER`:

```
[a-zA-Z]+([(a-zA-Z)*|(\d+)*|(_*)])*
```

and that regular expression never matches anything with a space character. (That regular expression has various problems; the characters `*`, `(`, `)`, `|` and `+` inside the second character class are treated as ordinary characters. See below for a correct regex.)

You could certainly match `in out` as a token in a manner similar to that suggested in your original question, prior to the edit. However,

```
t_KEYINOUT = r'in\sout'
```

will not work, because Ply does not use the common "maximum munch" algorithm for deciding which regular expression pattern to accept. Instead, it simply orders all of the patterns and picks the first one which matches, where the order consists of all of the tokenizing *functions* (in the order in which they are defined), followed by the token variables sorted in reverse order of regex length. Since `t_IDENTIFIER` is a function, it will be tried before the variable `t_KEYINOUT`. To ensure that `t_KEYINOUT` is tried first, it must be made into a function and placed *before* `t_IDENTIFIER`.

However, that is still not exactly what you want, since it will tokenize

```
in outwards
```

as

```
LexToken(KEYINOUT,'in out',1,0)
LexToken(IDENTIFIER,'wards',1,6)
```

rather than

```
LexToken(KEYIN,'in',1,0)
LexToken(IDENTIFIER,'outwards',1,3)
```

To get the correct analysis, you need to ensure that `in out` only matches if `out` is a complete word; in other words, if there is a word boundary at the end of the match. So one solution is:

```
reserved = {'in': 'KEYIN', 'out': 'KEYOUT'}

def t_KEYINOUT(t):
    r'in\sout\b'
    return t

def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'IDENTIFIER')  # Check for reserved words
    return t
```

---

However, it is almost certainly not *necessary* for the lexer recognize `in out` as a single token. Since both `in` and `out` are keywords, it is easy to leave it to the parser to notice when they are used together as an `in out` designator:

```
parameter: KEYIN IDENTIFIER
         | KEYOUT IDENTIFIER
         | KEYIN KEYOUT IDENTIFIER
```